# Scrapy crawler getting partial data

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy for crawling some website.

I need to get data every hour so I created a crontab to launch my crawlers. I made a python script for every crawler and another script that launch every "subscript".

So I have a "**master**" script that it's like

`"os.system("cd /home/.../directory1 ; python directory1Launch.py")"`

and some "**slave**" script that are like

"`os.system("scrapy crawl directory 1 -a start_url \"urls\" -o data.json")"`

for a certain number of crawlers.

That was working fine. Then I had to add some function in pipeline. Now a couple of crawler (that are working on the same site) crawl just a fraction of the data (2 items instead of 7 items).

The fact is that if I launch the "master" script manually everithing works just fine.

And the other crawler are working just like before.

Maybe it's a time problem (parser taking too much time?) but it would happen also when manually launched...

Any idea?

Comment: Is each script making more than one query?

Comment: Every script execute a crawler, some of it have more than one start_url in input from command line, some other have just one url but than they can make more request during the crawl if needed.

In general, if I have more than one url in input than I do one request for url, else I make some more request manually (with Request(response.url, meta={'item_data': day}, callback=self.scrape_Morning, dont_filter=True) ) or something like that.

Comment: I have executed (with crontab) without pipelines, and it worked...
I guess the problem is in the slow down introduced by pipelines. Does it make sense? The pipeline it's working, it doesn't give any errors...

Comment: Usually the most common problem with scraping is not giving the server enough time to breathe/respond. Try programming in pauses: `from time import sleep` gives you a tool for this. `sleep(1)` makes your script pause for 1 second, so you can adjust it as necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try, but it doesn't make sense that if I execute the same command manually it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, It works!
I guess the reason why it works with manual input without the sleep is because when you give the command by hand scrapy print a lot of log, so the time he "gain" with the print is enough to get the answer from the site.
Thank's again :D